# HTTP error 403 in Python 2.79 web scraping (eddywinch82)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been trying to web scrape .zip Files from a Flightsim Website link.

Here is the Python code:

```
`import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
#import urllib
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Create a new directory to put the files into
#Get the current working directory and create a new directory in it named test
cwd = os.getcwd()
newdir = cwd +"\\test"
print "The current Working directory is " + cwd
os.mkdir( newdir, 0777);
print "Created new directory " + newdir
newfile = open('zipfiles.txt','w')
print newfile


print "Running script.. "
#Set variable for page to be open and url to be concatenated 
url = "http://www.flightsim.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.flightsim.com/vbfs/fslib.php?do=search&fsec=62').read()

#File extension to be looked for. 
extension = ".zip"

#Use BeautifulSoup to clean up the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()

#Find all the links on the page that end in .zip
for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    links = url + anchor['href']
    if links.endswith(extension):
        newfile.write(links + '\n')
newfile.close()

#Read what is saved in zipfiles.txt and output it to the user
#This is done to create presistent data 
newfile = open('zipfiles.txt', 'r')
for line in newfile:
    print line + '/n'
newfile.close()

#Read through the lines in the text file and download the zip files.
#Handle exceptions and print exceptions to the console
with open('zipfiles.txt', 'r') as url:
    for line in url:
        if line:
            try:
                ziplink = line
                #Removes the first 48 characters of the url to get the name of the file
                zipfile = line[48:]
                #Removes the last 4 characters to remove the .zip
                zipfile2 = zipfile[:3]
                print "Trying to reach " + ziplink
                response = urllib2.urlopen(ziplink)
            except URLError as e:
                if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
                    print 'We failed to reach a server.'
                    print 'Reason: ', e.reason
                    continue
                elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
                    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
                    print 'Error code: ', e.code
                    continue
            else:
                zipcontent = response.read()
                completeName = os.path.join(newdir, zipfile2+ ".zip")
                with open (completeName, 'w') as f:
                    print "downloading.. " + zipfile
                    f.write(zipcontent)
                    f.close()
print "Script completed"
`
```

And when I run it I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Python 2.79\Web Scraping Code For .ZIP Files 2.py", line 22, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.flightsim.com/vbfs/fslib.php?do=search&fsec=62').read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`
```

Can someone tell me how I can bypass this problem ? I am pretty sure, its a blocking setup on the website. There are 2530 Files altogether, so individually downloading them on the website, will take too long.

Comment: This problem was sorted out for me, on another Website, someone wrote a Web Scraping Python Code for me. Eddie